# Why output from `stty -a < /dev/pts/0` on pts/1 is different than `stty -a` on pts/0?

Tags: linux, terminal, stty, pseudoterminal

If I type `stty -a` on `pts/0`, it shows `icanon` among other flags, which is expected.

However, if I run `stty` from a terminal which is not the controlling terminal of the (bash) shell that I am currently in, it outputs `-icanon`. To summarize:

- `stty -a < /dev/pts/0` from `pts/0`, gives `icanon`, same as `stty -a`
- `stty -a < /dev/pts/0` from `pts/1`, gives `-icanon`
- `stty -a < /dev/pts/1` from `pts/1`, gives `icanon`, same as `stty -a`
- `stty -a < /dev/pts/1` from `pts/0`, gives `-icanon`

What's going on?

Comment: I don't think you can redirect like that, but I haven't touched `stty` in many years. Maybe try [`--file=/dev/pts/0`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/stty.1.html)?

Comment: `--file=XXX` gives the same results. I think POSIX requires stty to use stdin anyways, so they are equivalent forms.

Comment: yes, that's basically the same question.

Answer (score 3):

Your terminal device's line discipline is not in canonical mode *when the shell's command-line editor is active*.  When GNU Readline, ZLE, editline, or another command-line editing library is actively presenting its editor, the shell has switched the terminal line discipline to non-canonical mode.  Think about it.  Line editors, which have their own interpretations of control characters (including special characters) and which respond immediately as each character is typed, couldn't work any other way with terminal I/O.

Canonical mode is restored every time that the line editor finishes a line.  Go to the first pseudoterminal, run an external command that runs for some length of time, such as `sleep`, and *then* see what is reported from the other pseudoterminal.

Comment: … and only now do I discover the duplicate at https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/226448/5132 .

Comment: OK, that would explain it. Does the bash shell line editor provide extra feature which the default canonical mode does not?